# Take a ScreenShot from Android Device as iPhone

Tags: android

I have a problem that I have to make an Android App which take a screenshot of Android device same as iPhone does. So, Is it possible to make such kind of Android App? If yes, then provide me some suggestions or example for doing the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, it's not possible unless the device is rooted.

**EDIT**

It's already available in ICS : [Take screenshots in ICS (Android 4.0)](http://alexsleat.co.uk/2011/11/28/how-to-take-screenshots-in-ice-cream-sandwich-android-4-0-x/)

Comment: is there also an API in ICS to take screenshots from a current view ?